# Prove commutative law of multiplication using peano axioms.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms, peano-axioms, formal-proofs

That is, prove $∀x∀y(x \cdot y=y \cdot x)$.

I have tried induction but it seems not work well. It may require the rule of additive cancellation to be proved. could someone please prove it please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a sense in which, if the axioms (and inferences) of peano arithmetic are complete, and if multiplication is completely (and correctly) defined, then there must be a proof of the commutivity of multiplication.  I would suggest, rather than looking for a proof of commutivity, look for a proof that there is a proof of commutivity, and the former should follow more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

From previous posts I know you are working with the following two axioms for multiplication:

$\forall x \: x \cdot 0 = 0$

$\forall x \forall y \: x \cdot s(y) = (x\cdot y) + x$

So here multiplication is recursively defined over the right operand. To prove commutation for multiplication you will have to prove its left-recursive counterparts:

$\forall x \: 0 \cdot x = 0$

$\forall x \forall y \: s(x) \cdot y = (x \cdot y) + y$

Both can be proven by induction. Once you have those, it is a fairly easy proof (again using induction) to get:

$\forall x \forall y \: x\cdot y = y \cdot x$

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the first theorem is fairly easy to prove, but may I please ask how to deal with $∀x∀ys(x)⋅y=(x⋅y)+y$ ?It seems to involve $1$ which does not occur in any axioms.

Comment: @Y.X. Great!  Glad I could help :)